# What are good Android headphones with Play/Pause and volume controls?

Tags: headphones, remote-control

I've had an iPod Touch for a while and am used  to controlling the music player without having to take the device from my pocket. I've had a look around for headphones that will work with the Samsung Galaxy S's TRRS connector and for players that would work with those headphones but haven't seen any combination that looks like it would work. Is this achievable? I'm also happy to consider alternatives like Bluetooth if that would work.

Comment: Also looking for similar answer for Google Nexus One. The stock headphone does not have volume controls. Only has play/pause/FF/REW.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a few Bluetooth headsets that would do this. for example the [MOTOROKR S9](http://direct.motorola.com/hellomoto/s9/):

> Works with any brand of Bluetooth®-enabled compatible phone or music device that supports Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP) and Audio Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP).

However this is a bit offputting:

> For optimal outdoor performance, position music device in close proximity to and in line of sight with the S9's internal antenna, which is located in the base behind the user's head. Placement of the music device in a front pocket is not recommended.

So they'd be fine as long as I strap my phone to my back or hold the phone like the model in the photo on the linked page is. Hmm.

A few other Bluetooth headsets I've looked at include:

- [Motorola HT820](http://www.fommy.co.uk/view-full-page.asp?divid=Vodafone&model=Vodafone+Samsung+Galaxy+S+i9000&cat=Headphones&skuno=7009) (a bit bulky, but does have a wired option)
- [Nokia BH-503](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/accessories/all-accessories/headsets/bluetooth-stereo-headsets/bh-503) (my current favourite).

I would still prefer a wired solution if possible so will keep looking. I have found that the Samsung Galaxy's TRRS connector is Left-Right-Mic-Ground, so it definitely won't work with iPhone headphones (which are Left-Right-Ground-Mic). However this does mean it *may* work with headphones from other vendors that have the same connection order, like Nokia, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I think Bluetooth is going to be your most flexible option.  I have a pair of [Rocketfish Bluetooth headphones](http://www.rocketfishproducts.com/products/mobile-phones-gps/RF-MAB2.html). They are fairly low cost, sound great, and include player controls on the left ear unit.  They support both the A2DP profile (for stereo playback) as well as the hands-free headset profile for voice calls.  The mic is acceptable, but not great.

Comment: Hmm. The link you provided makes no mention of hands-free, nor do I see a microphone?

Comment: I'm wearing them now, and use them for phone calls quite often :-)  If you don't take my word for it, at the bottom of that page there are links to the Manuals & Support.  Open the link for the user manual and you will find a diagram of the headphones on page 4 which points out the microphone.

Comment: I not only took your word, I ended up buying a pair.  I just thought it must have been a link to the wrong product, since surely they wouldn't keep features to their own product secret!  Anyway, great pair of headphones.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to stick with wired headset, since they are betetr supported by the software. I just bought the Motorola EH25. It has a mic and button, kind of like the iPod Touch. Generally they are around $20-$30, but I found them [here](http://www.all4cellular.com/motorola-stereo-wired-headset-eh25.html) for $7.

Answer (score 0):

I have a  Moto Droid and these two Audio enabled headsets:

[Sony DRBT50 Stereo Bluetooth Headset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PCCLPU) Good audio quality, especially bluetooth. Use with Pandora. Comfortable for serious listening. Works as both a Phone headset (Meh) and Stereo Audio (Yay!)

[Plantronics Voyager 855 Bluetooth Headset (Black)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UBNFT2) Good Conversation quality and microphone. Use this for Phone conversations and "talkie" podcasts. Supports both Phone (Yay!) and Stereo Audio (Meh)

Both of these headsets support audio controls in DoggCatcher and Music. Not sure about Pandora since I rarely use media controls now that my preferences are tuned.

Bluetooth is way more fragile than wired. You have pairing issues and interference issues, and battery draining/charging issues. Oh and it is way more expensive. Might be worth it, but don't start unless you think farting around with gadgets is a fun way to blow a weekend (and a couple hundred dollars).